# How to get parse and rewriting time from PostgreSQL query plans?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

The documentation clearly [states](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/using-explain.html)

> The Planning time shown by EXPLAIN ANALYZE is the time it took to
>   generate the query plan from the parsed query and optimize it. It does
>   not include parsing or rewriting.

Then how does one get this time which is not included (parsing and rewriting by themsevles)? I understand that one can take the total query time, but beyond that, is it possible to get this time individually in a different way?

The reason I ask is because I am in a situation where I cannot record total time taken (instead I want to arrive at it from the plan, which seems to be missing a bit of info).

Answer (score 2):

I sounds like you want [the settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-statistics.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-STATISTICS-MONITOR):

```
log_parser_stats
log_planner_stats
log_executor_stats
```

The format of the output is not pleasant to dig through, and the volume of output is also very high on a busy server unless you set them only in one session, but I don't think anything else will give you what you want.

To the plan as well, you would probably want to use this in conjunction with auto_explain.

Comment: that is what I want, but I am understanding that such an option to package the stats with the plan is totally unavailable? not sure how I feel about having to analyze log files for this task

Comment: I'm not sure what the alternative to log files would be.  I would think any client that will let you process the data client side (say, `set client_min_messages TO log` and do something useful with the log messages) would also let you time the query directly.  Why can't you time the queries?